# Daily Subscriptions not firing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a 2016 Enterprise SQL Server running SSRS with a few thousand subscriptions.  In the past few months a handful of daily subscriptions that should run between 8a-9a don't run.  When I query the reportServer db, I'll see that the ran yesterday and the next run date will be tomorrow.  It's always the ones between 8a-9am; or at least if it occurs other times the recipients aren't as noisy about missing reports as the C-Level execs are.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any ideas how to determine what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you receive an error sending message in the subscription last results?

Comment: I would also suggest, where possible, include a link in the subscription email, which will allow teams to run the report directly following a subscription failure. This may mitigate a lot of your problem. Failing that you will need to review any other factors that may be causing SSRS not to execute the subscription, i.e. server downtime - updates etc.

Comment: Check the exchange server logs as well?

Comment: in the ssrs logs I see:   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SchedulerNotRespondingException: The SQL Agent service is not running. This operation requires the SQL Agent service.;  However the agent was definitely running.  We have a large number of jobs running at that time.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with intermittent error SchedulerNotRespondingException, but the agent was running. We had to add a workaround to postpone the subscription for 15 minutes and then retry the operation